# Trying to produce exponential traffic

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to simulate an optical network algorithm in MATLAB for a homework project. Most of it is already done, but I have an issue with the diagrams I'm getting.

In the simulation I'm generating exponential traffic, however, for low lambda values (0.1) I'm getting very high packet drop rates (99%). I wrote a sample here which is very close to the testbench I'm running on my simulator.

```
% Run the simulation 10 times, with different lambda values
l = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10];

    for i=l(1):l(end)
        X = rand();
        % In the 'real' simulation the following line defines the time
        % when the next packet generation event will occur. Suppose that
        % i is the current time
        t_poiss = i + ceil((-log(X)/(i/10)));
        distr(i)=t_poiss;
    end

    figure, plot(distr)
    axis square
    grid on;
    title('Exponential test:')
```

The resulting image is

[image]

The diagram I'm getting in this sample is IDENTICAL to the diagram I'm getting for the drop rate/λ. So I would like to ask if I'm doing something wrong or if I miss something? Is this the right thing to expect?

Comment: What results are you expecting? I'm not sure I understand the problem.

Comment: In the above diagram, for values of λ*10 greater than 2 (x-axis), I'm getting an increasing "curve". I think that this is the normal. The weird part is the first instant huge drop.

Comment: Are you allowed to use the `poissrnd` function to generate the random poisson distribution?

Comment: Yes, I have no restrictions on how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is coming from might be a numerical problem. Since you are generating a random number for `X`, the number might be incredibly small - say, close to zero. If you have a number close to zero numerically, `log(X)` is going to be HUGE. So your calculation of `t_poiss` will be huge. I would suggest doing something like `X = rand() + 1` to make sure that `X` is never close to zero.

Comment: I'm using the exponential distribution to reproduce an event (packet generation) over time. If for any reason the X is greater than 1 I'm getting past time (negative number). Also the weird thing is why this isn't happening with greater values of λ and only for λ=0.1.